# Entity Framework entities different keys are mapped to same row

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using `Entity Framework`, just updated a few changes from the database, then came accross this error: `Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 903, 1239:Two entities with possibly different keys are mapped to the same row. Ensure these two mapping fragments map both ends of the AssociationSet to the corresponding columns.`

I understand the problem, however, I dont know what the offending tables are. The database has more than 50 tables, and there are hundreds of relationships between them. I have no idea where to start. The Stack Trace:

```
[MappingException: 
Tracker.msl(903,10) : error 3034: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 903, 1239:Two entities with possibly different keys are mapped to the same row. Ensure these two mapping fragments map both ends of the AssociationSet to the corresponding columns.
]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewDictionary.SerializedGenerateViews(EntityContainerMapping entityContainerMap, Dictionary`2 resultDictionary) +193
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewDictionary.SerializedGetGeneratedViews(EntityContainer container) +327
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0() +50
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Result.GetValue() +154
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg) +498
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewDictionary.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent, MetadataWorkspace workspace, StorageMappingItemCollection storageMappingItemCollection) +1596
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent, MetadataWorkspace workspace) +62
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent) +128
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ExpandView(ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter) +657
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ProcessScanTable(Node scanTableNode, ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter) +229
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ScanTableOp op, Node n) +57
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp.Accept(BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n) +47
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n) +121
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n) +139
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n) +62
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(FilterOp op, Node n) +295
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.FilterOp.Accept(BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n) +47
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n) +121
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n) +139
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n) +62
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitSortOp(SortBaseOp op, Node n) +47
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(ConstrainedSortOp op, Node n) +47
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ConstrainedSortOp.Accept(BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n) +47
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n) +121
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n) +139
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n) +39
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitPhysicalOpDefault(PhysicalOp op, Node n) +44
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(PhysicalProjectOp op, Node n) +47
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.PhysicalProjectOp.Accept(BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n) +47
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n) +121
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(Dictionary`2& tvfResultKeys) +112
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(PlanCompiler planCompilerState, StructuredTypeInfo& typeInfo, Dictionary`2& tvfResultKeys) +93
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets) +170
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(DbCommandTree ctree, List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets) +111
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory) +647

[EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory) +2623
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver) +68
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +151
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +220
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.CreateCommandDefinition(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree) +210
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator) +255
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +2430
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6() +83
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +448
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5() +271
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +251
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +648
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0() +68
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +68
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +4098209
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +83
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +107
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +197
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +155
   System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +287
   Tracker.Implementations.UserDetails.Tracker.Infrastructure.IUserDetails.getUser(String Email) +550
   TrackerV3MVC.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in c:\WorkSpace\Entire Solution\TrackerV3MVC\Controllers\HomeController.cs:32
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +101
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +211
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +223
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514928
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: have you tried deleting all the tables and re-adding them? the `update` feature doesn't work so well

Comment: Hi. What I actually just wanted to know is, isnt there a way I can get more information about this error? I at least need to know what tables are causing this. I know a solution to this problem, but I need to know where it originates. I have tried making break points and stepping into the DBCOntext, but no luck at all. For one reason or another, i cant drop and recreate this. Some issues were handled in the application that wouldnt necessarily be in the database design. Obviously not the best decision, but the project is 4 months in, due next week friday, and I just encountered this.

Comment: have you opened up the `edmx` file and navigated to the offended lines? what do they look like?

Comment: Thanks man. I found the offending table was the user_inrole table. It wasnt supposed to be there. So humbled by this error. wasted 24 hours on it. Maybe I should now go sleep. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes `Entity Framework` does not give precise indications about errors. And the `update model` tool does not work as well as it should....

In cases like these I usually clear the `edmx` file (delete all the tables) and add them again.

If that's not possible, open your `edmx` file (as an `xml` file) and navigate to the lines specified in the error, you might find the source of your troubles